# How is $i^3$ = $\sqrt{-i}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I new to complex numbers.So please don’t mind.

We know $i^2$ = -1.

Then $i^3$ is written as $= -i$

Then does it’s steps of writing follow  this:

$-1^2$= $i^3$= 1

So in terms i = It says in my book

= -  $\sqrt{-i}$.

How did we get this ?

I have done calculation mistake while writing this question.I have now answered this question.

Comment: How can $i^3=1$?

Comment: $\mathrm{i}= e^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: It is in my textbook.@ndhanson3

Comment: Certainly you must be mistaking $\sqrt{-1}$ for $\sqrt{-i}$.

Comment: Oh yes.@AndrewChin Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$i^3$ =   $\sqrt{-1}$. *  $\sqrt{-1}$.*  $\sqrt{-1}$.

Therefore it equals = -1 *  $\sqrt{-1}$.

Or we can write it also using the property he listed in his question.

$i^2$ * i = -i.

Remember:When a and b both are negative and are multiplied.

Therefore , it equals - $\sqrt{ab}$.

For the OP.

Answer (score -1):

$i = \sqrt{-1~}$ so $i^2 = -1$ and $i^3 = i^2 \cdot i = -1 \cdot \sqrt{-1~} = -\sqrt{-1~}$
Hope This helps!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are not wrong but you must use Math jax so that it easier for other users to understand your answer.@Issac